# Prevent the user entering numbers in java Scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am having some trouble preventing the user from entering numbers with the scanner class. This is what I have:

```
package palindrome;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word;
        String inverse = "";

        System.out.println("Write a sentence or word: ");

        while (!input.hasNext("[A-Za-z]+")) {
        System.out.println("Not valid! Try again: ");
        input.nextLine();
    }
        word = input.nextLine();

        word = word.replaceAll("\\s+","");
        word = word.toLowerCase();

        int length = word.length();
        length = length - 1;

        for (int i = length; i >= 0; i--) {
            inverse = inverse + word.charAt(i);
        }

        if (word.equals(inverse)) {
            System.out.println("Is a palindrome.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Is not a palindrome.");
        }

    }
}
```

Basically when I enter a word or sentence I want it to check if it has any numbers anywhere in the input, if it has then you need to enter another one until it doesn't. Here is an example of output:

- Write a sentence or word:

  --> 11
- Not valid! Try again:

  --> 1 test
- Not valid! Try again:

  --> test 1
- Is not a palindrome.

As you can see it works for most cases, but when I enter a word FIRST and then a space followed by a number it evaluates it without the number. I am assuming this is happening because in the while loop is checking for only input.hasNext but it should be input.hasNextLine I believe to check the entire string. However I cannot have any arguments if I do that. Help much appreciated!

Comment: Can you be more clear what you want plz?

Comment: @KickButtowski test 1 should not be valid (right now it executes as if it was) as it contains a number. I want it to detect it as an invalid option, no matter where the number is in the sentence.

Comment: Why not just put the `String` in both a `Stack` and a `Queue`. Dequeue and Pop  elements off the structures and compare them.

Comment: @Tdorno I am not sure what you mean by that, I am still pretty much at a basic level of coding.

Comment: @SilverKnight but your code does not work for plaindrom either i put abba and does not work?

Comment: Ahh, I see so the issue is collecting input containing multiple words.

Comment: @KickButtowski you might be doing something wrong, it is working for me http://puu.sh/bq0hl/64a7362eb4.png

Comment: @SilverKnight ya i found that right now lol

Comment: @SilverKnight so your user can enter one word at the time an other will not be count ? why you asks ur user for a sentence?

Comment: @SilverKnight Also I'd like to add that for the most part palindromes are **single words**. There are rare cases of palindromic sentences.

Comment: @Tdorno Yeah I know but I am using this for English/Spanish and in Spanish there are a decent amount of sentences, and I wanted to account for both! Thanks for your answer though, it worked too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your regex from: `[A-Za-z]+` to `^[A-Za-z]+$` in order to prevent numbers anywhere in the input-string