# How to filter out inputs to include only letters not numbers

Tags: java

Im trying to write a program that finds Palindromes in words, when I type a number it says that it is true and I want to prevent numbers from being used in the code. I am new to this so as much explanation you could give me would be welcome! If you could drop an example below that would be very welcome!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab08HC
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      boolean notFinished = false;
      do
      {
         System.out.print("Enter a string  ===>>  ");
         String str = input.nextLine();
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("Entered String:     " + str);
         System.out.println("Palindrome:         " + Palindrome.isPal(str));
         System.out.println("Almost Palindrome:  " + Palindrome.almostPal(str));   
         System.out.print("Do you wish to repeat this program [Y/N]?  ===>>  ");
         String repeat = input.nextLine();
         notFinished = (repeat.equals("Y")) || (repeat.equals("y"));
         System.out.println();
      }
      while (notFinished);
   }
}



class Palindrome
{
      
   public static boolean isPal(String s)
   {
   s = s.toUpperCase();
   String reverse = new StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString();
   if(reverse.equals(s))  
   {
   return true;
   }
   else
   {
   return false;
   }
   }

   
   
   private static boolean isLetter(String letter)
   {
   
   letter = letter.toUpperCase();
   int x = Integer.parseInt(letter);

   
   char character = letter.charAt(x);
   if(character >= 65 || character <= 90)
   {
   return true;
   }
   else
   {
   return false;
   }
    
   }
   
   
   
   private static String purge(String s)
   {
   String purged = "";
   s = s.toUpperCase();
   
   for(int x = 0; x < s.length(); x++)
   {
   String letter = s.substring(x,x+1);
   char character = s.charAt(x);
   if(Character.isLetter(character))
   {
   purged = purged + letter;
   }
   }
   return purged;
   }
    
    
   public static boolean almostPal(String s)
   {
   s = purge(s.toUpperCase());
   
   String reverse = new StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString();
   if(reverse.equals(s))  
   {
   return true;
   }
   else
   {
   return false;
   }
}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent the user entering numbers in java Scanner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715521/prevent-the-user-entering-numbers-in-java-scanner)

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! What *exactly* seems to be the problem? I've played with your code and it seems to classify palindromes correctly. If a palindrome contains any digits, it is regarded as an *"Almost Palindrome"*, as expected.